# Save images with high resolution with matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, format, dataset, resolution

i'm generating a dataset from 1D signals with a 2D transformation that generates 2D pictures. I'm using matplotlib to save the output with the following line:

```
plt.savefig(name_s , dpi = 'figure' , bbox_inches='tight', pad_inches=0.0 , format='png')
```

I'm having some trouble unerstanding if an high numerical dpi value is needed or if it is just a rescale, in particular when with the dpi = 'figure' parameter the function outputs a lower resolution image.

Moreover, if there is a specific format i can use to generate or save better images or any advice in general is gladly accepted.

Comment: You have also to set the size of the figure `figure.set_size_inches(12, 8)`, if the size is large, the figure will appear better because the dpi defines the resolution by inche.

Comment: dpi is dots-per-inch.  The higher this number, the more resolution you will have, but the larger the file.  Save one at dpi=50, and one at dpi=300, and see what the difference is.